Log redirect in nginx
We use nginx as a reverse proxy.
We have a few old hostnames that we are phasing out, and we want to generate a log of requests to those old hosts so we can easily identify places where the host is still being used (and a year from now, be confident that we can retire the DNS entries, etc... without wiping out a critical production dependency).
The nginx entries for the retired hosts return 301s.
I've added an access_log entry to the handler in question:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name oldhost.example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access-oldhost.log main;
    return 301 $scheme://newhost.example.com$request_uri;
}

This results in the /var/log/nginx/access-oldhost.log file being created - but it is empty, even after we hit the old URL and get the 301.
I have tried putting the access_log line before and after the return.
I have added log_subrequest on; to the http section of nginx.conf:
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_subrequest  on;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    
    log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] - [$request_time ms/$upstream_response_time ms] - $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for <-> $scheme:$server_name [$status] <-> $upstream_addr [$upstream_status] : "$request" $http_referer';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    server_tokens off;

    #gzip  on;

    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

The server{} block is in one of the conf.d/*.conf files.
With log_subrequest on; we still don't get log output (to our main access log or to the access-oldhost.log file).
Hopefully someone can point me at what I'm doing wrong!

Problem is resolved.  My testing was hitting the wrong endpoint (embarrassing mistake).
The magic that made everything work was log_subrequest  on;
